Spring-boot Mongodb Takes longer to find All
I have around 4000 records in my table (3MB) in total.
A few days ago, my application became slow when I run findAll(). (normally, it takes 3 seconds to get all data, but now it takes 30 seconds to get all data).
By checking the log, I can see that, for first 101 records, it took 800ms but for the rest 3000+ records took around 25seconds to process from "getMore" Command.
I wonder if there is anything changed from mongodb service. If not, how should I fix this issue?
2024-06-25 23:12:28.282 DEBUG 92737 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "find" started on database xxxxxx(myDB) using a connection with driver-generated ID 7 and server-generated ID 359278 to ac-ktqn9ck-shard-00-02.dxlowxv.mongodb.net:27017. The request ID is 126. Command: {"find": "store_info", "filter": {}, "$db": "(myDB)", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1719371540, "i": 17}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "seWJAmzUG+s7FNRGd8quBA56qiU=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7329958630948601874}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "DOjrGyGyTxGodObhFX8SBw==", "subType": "04"}}}}
2024-06-25 23:12:29.130 DEBUG 92737 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "find" succeeded in 844.27 ms using a connection with driver-generated ID 7 and server-generated ID 359278 to ac-ktqn9ck-shard-00-02.dxlowxv.mongodb.net:27017. The request ID is 126. Command reply: {"cursor": {"firstBatch": [...(my data here)]
2024-06-25 23:12:29.131 DEBUG 92737 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.operation             : Received batch of 101 documents with cursorId 3203780083378422937 from server ac-ktqn9ck-shard-00-02.dxlowxv.mongodb.net:27017
2024-06-25 23:12:29.144 DEBUG 92737 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "getMore" started on database TPSI_PROD using a connection with driver-generated ID 7 and server-generated ID 359278 to ac-ktqn9ck-shard-00-02.dxlowxv.mongodb.net:27017. The request ID is 127. Command: {"getMore": 3203780083378422937, "collection": "store_info", "$db": "(MYDB)", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1719371548, "i": 9}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "a6bHBg5M4fkAfg3nUqNCely4w64=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7329958630948601874}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "DOjrGyGyTxGodObhFX8SBw==", "subType": "04"}}}}
2024-06-25 23:12:55.562 DEBUG 92737 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "getMore" succeeded in 26352.68 ms using a connection with driver-generated ID 7 and server-generated ID 359278 to ac-ktqn9ck-shard-00-02.dxlowxv.mongodb.net:27017. The request ID is 127. Command reply: {"cursor": {"nextBatch": [...(rest of my data)]
2024-06-25 23:12:55.598 DEBUG 92737 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.operation             : Received batch of 3608 documents with cursorId 0 from server ac-ktqn9ck-shard-00-02.dxlowxv.mongodb.net:27017


Can you tell (please update your question) what version of MongoDB and Spring Boot you are working with and include the specific API (MongoTemplate, MongoRepository, Java driver native query, etc.) to retrieve all data (or is it with a query predicate).  See if this post has info useful for your case: Specifying cursor options when returning a Stream in Spring Data MongoDB?

If you are building a CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) application and the records have a consistent structure you might want to consider using a relational database like PostgresSQL instead of MongoDB.
